# PCRECPP (pcre) extract hostname from url code problem

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I have this simple piece of code in c++:

```
int main(void)
    {
        string text = "http://www.amazon.com";
        string a,b,c,d,e,f;
        pcrecpp::RE re("^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)");
        if(re.PartialMatch(text, &a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f)) 
        {
            std::cout << "match: " << f << "\n";
            // should print "www.amazon.com"
        }else{
            std::cout << "no match. \n";
        }       
        return 0;
    }
```

When I run this it doesn't find a match.
I pretty sure that the regex pattern is correct and my code is what's wrong.
If anyone familiar with pcrecpp can take a look at this Ill be grateful.

EDIT:
Thanks to [Dingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95286/dingo), it works great. 
another issue I had is that the result was at the sixth place - "f".  
I edited the code above so you can copy/paste if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code contains `??(` which is a trigraph in C++ for `[`. You'll either need to disable trigraphs or do something to break them up like:

```
pcrecpp::RE re("^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??" "([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do
cout << re.pattern() << endl;
to double-check that all your double-slashing is done right (and also post the result).

Looks like

^((\w+):///?)?((\w+):?(\w+)?@)?([^/\?:]+):?(\d+)?(/?[^\?#;\|]+)?([;\|])?([^\?#]+)?\??([^#]+)?#?(\w*)

The hostname isn't going to be returned from the first capture group, why are you using parentheses around for example \w+ that you aren't wanting to capture?